# Floating point numbers in XML

Tags: c#, xml, floating-point

what is the best way to handle floating point numbers in XML?
If I have, for instance:

```
double a = 123.456;
```

and I would like to keep it as

```
<A> 123.456 </A>
```

simply using 
...

```
myDoc.createTextNode(a.ToString());
```

is fine?
Or should it be done with some Globalization stuff to make it region-independent?

Comment: I really hope that the textual representation of a plain old floating point number does not depend on what region you are in.

Comment: @robert I seriously hope it does :) Why should every one be forced to use the US format? decimal numbers have been represented xx,yy for longer than the states have existed (not saying that decimal comma necessarily came before decimal point). So stating that xx.yy is the "plain old floating point" format is of by a light year or so :)

Comment: the answer to your question doesn't depend on which .NET programming  language you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [XmlConvert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlconvert?view=net-6.0) class, specifically the [XmlConvert.ToString Method (Double)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlconvert.tostring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Xml_XmlConvert_ToString_System_Double_).

> [The XmlConvert Class] provides methods for converting between common language runtime types and XML Schema definition language (XSD) types. When converting data types the values returned are locale independent.